# Why does CreatePipe() fail with ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL?

Tags: winapi, popen

We tried to write a replacement for the Win32 `_popen()` function using `CreatePipe()` (see https://nrubsig.kpaste.net/b9 for the code).

It works as a standalone application, but if we embed it into our software (filesystem driver, where threads impersonate the users which access the filesystem), it fails with `ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL` (1346) for the "SYSTEM" user.

Comment: Look for your thread token. Probably it have identification level.

Comment: Can I temporary swap the token somehow ?

Comment: Wrong question. How is impersonation is implemented. For what ? Why wrong impersonation level. All can be done if have deep understanding what we doing